# Create "Draft" Calendar entry via REST API

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I like to create a draft calendar entry for a user via the office 365 REST API, including all attendees, time etc. 
For missing information the user should complete this entry afterwards in the webapp.
The problem: All attendees receive an invitation by creating the "draft". Is there a way to prevent the sending of the invitation?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

No, the API sends the invites once you create the event. There's not really a concept of a "draft" event.